# Bootstrap lightbox interfering with Bootstrap CSS

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, lightbox

I'm trying to use bootstrap lightbox for images within a site I am building that uses Bootstrap 3(just downloaded from the site yesterday). For some reason the bootstrap.css is interfering with lightbox and I can't figure it out.

The thumbnail is appearing and the screen 'dims' when the image is clicked but the larger image never appears. I'm lost and can't figure it out.

Here is the lightbox download:
http://www.jasonbutz.info/bootstrap-lightbox/

Link to my site:
http://dev.catalanousa.com/code_testing/code/test_gallery.php

The red square should get bigger when clicked but its not happening. It's also breaking my side nav and top nav(appearance wise).

Thanks

Comment: Look at your browsers JS console. When clicking the image this gets printed: ```Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery```. Maybe that has something to do with it...

Comment: I'm pretty sure I have that included using <script> tags. Also that doesn't explain why its breaking my header and side navs.

Answer (score 0):

The jquery-file is not where you included it at.
Your link refers to http://dev.catalanousa.com/code_testing/code/js/jquery.js, which is a 404

Answer (score 0):

Fix the jquery file location, and try loading the script in the header of your page.